# Asp.Net Web API Routing not hitting custom action

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Here is my code:

```
public class SecurityController : ApiController
{
    //GET api/Security/Current
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCurrent(){

    }
    //POST api/Security/Login
    public HttpResponseMessage PostLogin(LoginModel model){

    }
}

public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("Default")] //GET api/Orders
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(){

    }

    [ActionName("Default")] //GET api/Orders/2
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(long id){

    }

    [ActionName("Default")] //POST api/Orders/
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Order order){

    }

    [ActionName("Default")] //DELETE api/Orders/2
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(long id){

    }
    [HttpPost] //POST api/Orders/2/PerformAction
    public HttpResponseMessage PerformAction(long id, ActionMsg action){

    }

}
```

//Route definitions

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ActionApi", "api/{controller}/{action}");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("WithActionApi", "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Default" }, new { id = @"\d+" });
```

My routing is not working.

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
```

What is the correct route definition for my API controller?
Thanks!

Comment: What URL are you using? Why are you using [ActionName(Default)]?

Comment: I was under the assumption that route will map to the action in controller with same action name. That is if I have ActionName attribute with a action then `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Default" }, new { id = @"\d+" });` will be used for routing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your SecurityController to:

```
public class SecurityController : ApiController
{
    //GET api/Security/Current
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("current")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCurrent(){

    }
    //POST api/Security/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("login")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostLogin(LoginModel model){

    }
}
```

And then change your routing to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ActionApi",
  "api/{controller}/{action}",
  null,
  new { action = @"[a-zA-Z]+" });

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("WithActionApi",
  "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}");

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi",
  "api/{controller}/{id}",
  new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Default" },
  new { id = @"\d*" });
```

Note the regex "\d*" is required in the last route rather than "\d+".

Answer (score 0):

Please remove: `[ActionName("Default")]`

None of your route definitions refer to it. In fact, you don't really need action names at all for web api in general.

With ActionName removed, and with `"api/{controller}/{action}"` route, you should be able to hit that action by using `http://url/api/orders` which will call `public HttpResponseMessage Get()`

Comment: Didn't work. Except `api/Orders/2/PerformAction` all throws 404