# WebApi action routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to support multiple GET requests on the same controller for sub-actions on the models, however I can't get the routes to work properly. I am trying to support -

```
/{controller}/{id}/{action}
```

while not stepping on the default

```
/{controller}/{id}
```

I tried creating another route config like so -

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}"
        );
```

However, this allows for routes at **/{controller}/{id}/{action}**, but the **/{controller}/{id}** methods stop working with a "multiple actions found" exception.

Here are examples of the three GET methods I am trying to expose-

```
    public HttpReponseMessage GetItem() 
    {

    }
    public HttpResponseMessage GetItem(int id)
    {

    }
    public HttpResponseMessage GetItemMetaData(int id)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Web API 2 then try using [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) which makes these kinds of situations very easy to handle. If you are still on Web API 1 then have a look at [Attribute Routing for Web API](http://attributerouting.net/). If for some reason you don't want to use either, you can specify you routes in more detail, like so:

```
// Map your specific route first.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "NestedApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/items",
    defaults: new{action = "GetItems"}
);
// You can have other specific routes here.

// Map all other GET requests to a Get method.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultGetApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Get" },
    constraints: new{httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get)}
);

// Use default route for all the rest.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: That looks really promising. Kind of a silly question, but I can I tell if I am running WebAPI2?

Comment: @thebringking I think you can check System.Web.Http, if it's version 5.0.0.0 or higher then you have Web API 2, if it's lower then you have Web API 1.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Looks like I am running WebAPI2, but the project is a VS2012 project. So no AttributeRouting for me.

Comment: You actually don't need VS2013, with that you just get Web API 2 by default with new project. You can also install Web API 2 via NuGet which is also available for VS2012. If you have Web API 2 then try adding a `Route` attribute to an action method and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this answer [Asp.Net Web API Routing not hitting custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184798/asp-net-web-api-routing-not-hitting-custom-action/17187762#17187762) on SO question as starting point. It helped me a lot when I designed custom routes in my application.

In order to debug all custom routes I use [ASP.NET Web API Route Debugger](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiRouteDebugger/) by default.