# Dealing with multiple GET actions Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new to WEB API and trying to set up routing for multiple GET actions.

**Controller Code**

```
// Get api/values
public IEnumerable<tblUser> Get()
{
    //whatever 
}

// Get api/values/action
[ActionName("GetByQue")]
public IEnumerable<tblQue> GetQue()
{
    //whatever 
}

// Get api/values/action
[ActionName("GetUserScore")]
public IEnumerable<tblScore> GetScore(string user)
{
   //whatever 
}
```

**Config**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "GetByQue" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultStringApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "GetUserScore" }
);
```

When I try with **http://localhost:54118/api/remote/GetByQue** URL getting this error

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "MessageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' in 'HydTechiesApi.Controllers.HydTechiesApiController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
}
```

is my routing wrong? Any help would be valuable as I am not able to find a solution.

Comment: Have a look at Jons answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184798/asp-net-web-api-routing-not-hitting-custom-action/17187762#17187762

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You made **a couple of mistakes** in your route. As your example code below:

   ```
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultActionApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
     defaults: new { action = "GetByQue" });
     //url:   http://localhost:54118/api/remote/GetByQue
   ```

(1).  *routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}".*  you specify your route has an id and it is not Optional. So your URL must have id. That's what your error showed.you can handle with the issue like below:

```
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

(2). *defaults: new { action = "GetByQue" });*   you did not say any thing about action in your **routeTemplate**.   your **defaults** about action, which **does not** have any meaning.

(3). From your **route**, your **URL** should look like *http://localhost:54118/api/remote/5* , you should not get mutiple get method by your route.

2. There are some solutions, which you may use:

(1). change route like below:

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
```

please add [HttpGet] in each method just in cause.

```
     [HttpGet]
     public IEnumerable<tblUser> Get()
      {......}

     [HttpGet]
     [ActionName("GetByQue")]
     public IEnumerable<tblQue> GetQue()
     {......}

     [HttpGet]
     [ActionName("GetUserScore")]
       public IEnumerable<tblScore> GetScore(string user)
       {......}
```

Now you can use URL like *http://localhost:54118/api/remote/GetByQue*

Very Useful Tips: Using [Route("")] tag to specify parameters
**You also have to change Route like above (1)

in Controller, please specify request method to make sure the get method

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetUserScore")]
    [Route("api/remote/GetScore/{user}")]
     public IEnumerable<tblScore> GetScore(string user)
    {.....}
    //URL: http://localhost:54118/api/remote/GetScore/user
```

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `{action}` to `routeTemplate` instead of `{id}` in the second configuration

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "GetByQue" }
);
```

also you can try to use route attribure on action :

```
[ActionName("GetByQue")]
[Route("api/remote/GetByQue")]
public IEnumerable<tblQue> GetQue()
{
    //whatever 
}
```

or change order(the second configuration and first configuration) of configuration in WebApiConfig.cs